# How to use an attribute from one class in an another class?

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2  files: `user.py` (where I am doing all the printing) and `follower.py` (just to give follower data). I want to print the follower name via `user.py` but getting attribute error there.

- `user.py`

  ```
  from follower import Follower

  class User:

    def __init__(self, user_email, user_name):

      self.email=user_email
      self.name=user_name

    def print_details(self):

       print(f" user details : {user1.name}\n{user1.email}")
  user1=User("ABC@gmail.com", "ABCDEF")


  user1.print_details()

  print(Follower.name)

  Follower.message_from_follower()
  ```
- `follower.py`

  ```
  class Follower:

   def __init__(self,follower_name, job, loc):

      self.name = follower_name
      self.job = job
      self.location = loc

   def message_from_follower():

       return "Good day"


  f_details= Follower(" XYZ", "teacher", "AUS")
  ```

Comment: The _class_ `Follower` doesn't itself have a `name` attribute, which is presumably the error you're seeing. Did you mean to access `f_details`, an _instance_ of that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now sure you are trying to do here. If you want to print name of the follower ("XYZ") then you probably want to import the instance `f_details` instead of the *class* `Follower`.

But I wouldn't recommend to import instance. Instantiate the class in `user.py` instead.

```
f_details= Follower(" XYZ", "teacher", "AUS")
print(f_details.name)
```